# Why does `pip list` not show all Python packages installed by `apt` on Debian / Ubuntu?

Tags: python, ubuntu, pip, debian

On Debian based Linux distributions `pip` usually detects Python packages installed by `apt` (in `/usr/lib/pythonX/dist-packages`). However, this is not valid for `PyQt5` for example (`PyQt5` does not show up when running `pip list` or `pip freeze`). Does anyone know why?

With Docker you can run the following steps to reproduce the problem:

- Run a Debian unstable:

  ```
  docker run -it debian:unstable
  ```
- Install `python3-pip` and `python3-pyqt5`:

  ```
  apt update
  apt install --no-install-recommends python3-pip python3-pyqt5
  ```
- Run

  ```
  pip3 list
  ```

  Only `pip` will be listed.
- Install `python3-requests`

  ```
  apt install --no-install-recommends python3-requests
  ```

  and run

  ```
  pip3 list
  ```

  again. The `requests` package will be listed.

Comment: Run Python and then see what ```help('modules')``` outputs? Can you see PyQt5 in there?

Comment: Could you also show the o/p of PyQt5 installation?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, look what files are installed by the package:

```
dpkg-query -L python3-requests
```

In the output you will see:

/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/requests-2.18.4.egg-info/PKG-INFO

This file starts with:

```
Metadata-Version: 1.1
Name: requests
Version: 2.18.4
```

The `python3-pyqt5` package does not contain such file.

I can imagine, that some of the Debian packages do and others don't include this metadata.

The Debian FAQ states: (https://wiki.debian.org/Python/FAQ)

> We don't want to provide ".egg" files within the .deb. However we want
>   to make the "egg meta-information" available so that users can use
>   eggs if they so wish. Python >= 2.5 does that by default in distutils.
>   For setuptools based setup.py you need to pass the option
>   "--single-version-externally-managed" to the "setup.py install" call.

Answer (score 0):

It is indeed true that PyQt5 doesn't show up in the `pip list` output. Instead `pycairo` and `PyGObject` would show up.
If you execute `python3` and then run `import PyQt5` it imports without any errors. I have checked it on a docker container with a base image of Ubuntu, however it should work the same for Debian.

```
root@d6b7f119b352:/# python3
Python 3.6.7rc1 (default, Sep 27 2018, 09:51:25)
[GCC 8.2.0] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import PyQt5
>>>
```

Or

```
>>> from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QWidget, QLabel
>>>
```